# Button.set_hexpand(false) doesn't stop button from expanding

Tags: rust, gtk, gtk4

I am building a GUI Application using GTK4.8.3. I want two `ScrolledWindow`s where one (containing a `ListBox`) can expand horizontally and the other (containing a `Button`) cannot. More precisely, I want to restrict the button's ability to `hexpand`.

From the GTK documentation, I am aware that [Setting `hexpand` explicitly will override the automatic expand behavior](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/method.Widget.set_hexpand.html).

When I use the following code snippet to create the widgets and attempt to restrict horizontal expansion, my button can still expand horizontally, along with its parent `ScrolledWindow`. Why is this and how can I fix it?

```rust
let hyphens_scrollbox = ListBox::builder()
    .width_request(windows::WIDTH)
    .hexpand(true)
    .build();

let hyphens_scrollwindow = ScrolledWindow::builder()
    .width_request(windows::WIDTH)
    .height_request(customising::SCROLL_HEIGHT)
    .hexpand(true)
    .vexpand(true)
    .hscrollbar_policy(PolicyType::Never)
    .vscrollbar_policy(PolicyType::Always)
    .child(&hyphens_scrollbox)
    .build();

let details_scrollwindow = ScrolledWindow::builder()
    .width_request(windows::WIDTH)
    .height_request(entries::CONTAINER_HEIGHT)
    .hscrollbar_policy(PolicyType::Never)
    .vscrollbar_policy(PolicyType::Automatic)
    .hexpand(false)
    .child(&details_scrollbox)
    .build();

let new_button = Button::builder()
    .label("Add new group")
    .margin_bottom(buttons::MARGIN)
    .hexpand(false)
    .build();

details_scrollwindow.append(&new_button);

let defaultsbox = GtkBox::builder()
    .orientation(Orientation::Vertical)
    .width_request(windows::WIDTH)
    .build();

defaultsbox.append(&hyphens_scrollwindow);
defaultsbox.append(&details_scrollwindow);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason which is very confusing, there seems to be a relation between the "expand" properties and the [`gtk4::Align` property](https://gtk-rs.org/gtk4-rs/stable/latest/docs/gtk4/enum.Align.html) which goes nearly undocumented.

By setting this `gtk4::Align` property as well as the `hexpand` on the button only, I could get your case to work as you want it. For example:

```rust
let new_button = Button::builder()
    .label("Add new group")
    .margin_bottom(buttons::MARGIN)
    .hexpand(false)
    .halign(Align::Start)
    .build();
```

Visually:

[image: Not expanding]

Disclaimer: I don't know Rust and I have nothing here to test this code. Let me know if it does not work. I could only try it in C++.

Comment: Thank you. This worked for me. https://imgur.com/a/vP6ljFe